# Image won't load on Android using DrawImage function - JavaScript HTML5 Android PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm currently making a game using PhoneGap and have tried to deploy the game via Adobe PhoneGap Build. However, when I opened the app on my Android phone, it just showed blank white screen while on my Ripple Emulator, it showed all of the elements (images, audios, accelerometer, touch events) perfectly. The first screen of the app should be a welcome image (imported from img/*.jpg) and some touch events (for pressed button validation).

Here's my code in index.html

```
    var hello=new Image();
    var state = "start";

    function draw(){
                switch(state)
                {
                    case 'start' :
                        drawStart();
                        break();
                        ...
                }
                        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }...
```

The function drawStart() code...

```
 function drawStart(){
                alert("drawStart called"); //just a test
                var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.font="50px Georgia"; //just a test
                var text1width = ctx.measureText("Labyrinth").width; //just a test
                ctx.fillText("Labyrinth",(canvas.width/2)-(text1width/2) ,canvas.height/2 - 100); //just a test
                hello.src="img/Hello.jpg";
                    ctx.drawImage(hello,0,0);


 };
```

and the body...

```
<body>
        <script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            draw();
        });
        </script>

        <canvas id="canvas" height="800" width="480">
        </canvas>

</body>
```

I put an alert and context draw functions into my drawStart function and they didn't even appear on my Android phone. What's wrong and what should I do to fix this?